# Repeat until true

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

How do I repeat this function until it find the image class I'm looking for? Assume the img.header will only exist on some of the random id range given. Without the use of headers please.

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$randomID = mt_rand(100, 1000);
$url = "http://newspaper.com/article/".$randomID;

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($url);

//Find img
$element = $html->find('img.header');

//Check if image was found              
if (strpos($element,'img') == false) {
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    //Repeat until find('img.header') is true//
    ///////////////////////////////////////////
} else {
    echo $element->src;
}

?>
```

Comment: Do a fiddle for this to get fast answer

Comment: What does ` print_r() ` of this function give ? `$dom = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));`

Comment: @jimmyobonyo how do I include the simple html dom in that?

Comment: What, print_r($element)?

Comment: Appy above function then apply `preg_match` on the content you have got with `<img>` element

Comment: Also try using `curl` or `guzzle`

Comment: Is there any (good) reason why you want to use random ids?

Comment: @VolkerK Not really I guess. I just wanna find one id that contains what I want, and I want the result to be random? Just doing this for learning purposes and a bit of fun.. I have had it work with an infinite loop, then I get the response I want in like 8s max. Is that bad?

Comment: I'm sure finding a random game on Steam could be resolved with one of their API's or something, but that's not the point u know

Comment: "in like 8s max. Is that bad?" - Is it? It's your choice. Is 8 seconds acceptable? Do you expect a faster approach (on average)? Without further information I'd say that just firing up the random generator like that doesn't improve anything ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK I'm a newb and know no other methods. Besides, brute forcing sounds quite appealing. What I mean by bad is, do I put a stress on the website I'm scraping which could be considered bad by them? I guess Steam's a bad example there, but a smaller webpage.

Comment: Till I get good or have another option in my arsenal I'll just have to "fire that ole' random generator up!".

Comment: If you have no information about the distribution of the element you're looking for scanning page 1,2,3,4,5 is as fruitful and as stressful for the site as with random ids (the latter being actually worse if you don't keep track of the previously scanned ids because of re-scans).

Comment: Your script would time out by the way (`set_time_limit()`). You'll also probably be doing what @VolkerK has stated (*and that's a bitch, I've been there before lol*). Anyways, you'd probably want some sort of `do { /* do your stuff */} while(strpos($element,'img') == false);`, but loops aren't always fun haha

Comment: @VolkerK Right, okay. With a span of 400 000 random numbers that's not a very big chance though, right? Is there an easy way for me to see how many times I have to scrape the target till I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Darren It doesn't time out if I just call the same function again within the if, it works but takes a few seconds..

Comment: "way for me to see" Do you mean a) calculate an expectation value in advance? That depends on the "some" in "Assume the img.header will only exist on some of the random id range given" and whether the distribution is random or not. Or b) keep track of how many cycles your script needed to find the element (i.e. looking back after the fact)?

Comment: No like after. Can I echo out for instance, what how many different ids (as in example.com/article/id) that were visited before what I was looking for was found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many possible ways, one of the simpler examples:

```
<?php
$ids = range(100, 400000); // RAM is so cheap
shuffle($ids); // still not convinced it makes a difference, but why not...

foreach( $ids as $index=>$id ) {
    // <-- maybe you want to add some output here, so you can see that the script is still running.
    $url = "http://newspaper.com/article/".$id;
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    // edit: <-- some error handling here. See documentation of simple_html_dom on how to check $html for error conditions
    $element = $html->find('img.header');
    if ( $element ) {
        // found it
        // and the ids you've had to visit before finding the element are
        $visited = array_slice($ids, 0, $index+1);  
        break; // no need to go on, exit foreach-loop
    }
}

if ( !isset($visited) ) {
    // the element was never found....
}
else {
    // $html, $element and even $id should be still valid
    // so, you can use them here for further processing
}
```